# Getting Device Info Programmatically in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to know whether the following are possible in the current windows phone 7 SDK:

- Getting the device's OS version
  programmatically.
- Detecting programmatically
  whether the data connection is
  available in the device or not
- Programmatically getting the type of network
  connection that the device is
  currently having either wifi or LAN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the OS version by doing using [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx). The numbers at the end will be the current running version. You can confirm this on your phone by going to `Settings...About` and seeing if the numbers match.

You can use the [NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method to determine if there is any data connection available.

To determine the type of connection, you can use [NetworkInterface.GetInternetInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.networkinformation.networkinterface.getinternetinterfacetype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). This will return a valume of enum [NetworkInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). If the value is `Ethernet`, the user is plugged into the computer and using its data connection. (Of course, you should test the values returned to confirm that they're what you expected them to be).